# Interface with generic method parameter type in list

Tags: java, generics

I have a HashMap that links specific RequestTypes to separate LinkedLists. The lists consists of an interface with a generic type. I have no problems adding to the lists in the map but I can't seem to get the lists out of the map.

I'll show you two of my tries and there corresponding errors. First I'll show you the interface and my Map when I want to call the method in the interface.

```
public interface IRequestListener<Result> {
    public void resultUpdated(Result result);
}

private HashMap<RequestType, LinkedList<IRequestListener<?>>> requestListenerMap = 
    new HashMap<RequestType, LinkedList<IRequestListener<?>>>();
```

In the following code, RequestType and Notification are two simple enums.

Here is the first try:

```
Notification notification = Notification.AVOID;
LinkedList<IRequestListener<?>> listeners = 
    requestListenerMap.get(RequestType.NOTIFICATION);
for(IRequestListener<?> listener : listeners) {
    listener.resultUpdated(notification); // ERROR ON THIS LINE
}
```

That causes the following error:

```
The method resultUpdated(capture#1-of ?) in the type 
IRequestListener<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for 
the arguments (Notification)
```

Here is the second try:

```
Notification notification = Notification.AVOID;
LinkedList<IRequestListener<Notification>> listeners = 
    requestListenerMap.get(RequestType.NOTIFICATION); // ERROR ON THIS LINE
for(IRequestListener<Notification> listener : listeners) {
    listener.resultUpdated(notification);
}
```

That causes the following error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from LinkedList<IRequestListener<?>> 
to LinkedList<IRequestListener<Notification>>
```

I'm thinking that I'm getting tripped up by the inheritance/casting issues that are tricky with generics but I can't figure out how. I don't want to extend Notification since Result in the interface can be either a Notification or an Integer at this time. At a later time I might also add the possibility to have a List as a Result.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to constrain your `Result` type parameter to extend `Notification`:

```
private HashMap<RequestType, LinkedList<IRequestListener<? extends Notification>>> 
    requestListenerMap = new HashMap<>(); // Assuming Java 7

...

LinkedList<IRequestListener<? extends Notification>> listeners = 
    requestListenerMap.get(RequestType.NOTIFICATION);
for(IRequestListener<? extends Notification> listener : listeners) {
    listener.resultUpdated(notification);
}
```

Now if that's not appropriate for the map declaration - because you'd want to store other lists for other entries - you may need an unsafe cast:

```
private HashMap<RequestType, LinkedList<IRequestListener<?>>> requestListenerMap = 
    new HashMap<RequestType, LinkedList<IRequestListener<?>>>();

...

LinkedList<IRequestListener<?>> listeners = 
    requestListenerMap.get(RequestType.NOTIFICATION);
for (IRequestListener<?> listener : listeners) {
    // Note that this cast is unsafe.
    IRequestListener<? extends Notification> notificationListener = 
        (IRequestListener<? extends Notification>) listener;
    notificationListener.resultUpdated(notification);
}
```

Fundamentally you *can't* do this safely, as the execution-time type won't include the type argument. But you'll get a `ClassCastException` when you call `resultUpdated` if it's inappropriate.

Comment: Sorry no, I also want to be able to pass Integers and in a later stage perhaps even lists. I've updated the question with this information. Than you though.

Comment: @rattmuff: I didn't suggest making it extend it in the interface itself - I suggested making it extend it in the *usage* of the interface.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you very much. I tried these unsafe casts before posting but I obviously didn't get it right. I tried to cast `listener = (Cast...) listener`. Obviously I needed to declare a new variable.